# insert multiple rows in transactions, and if one fails let the rest be inserted

Tags: mysql, node.js, pdo, transactions, insert-into

I have an applications which collects hotel name and address data from different websites.

I need to insert them in bunches - 10 at once - into a mysql db. 
If one fails (for example the current hotel name is more 100 characters whereas the hotel_name column is type of char(75)) then the ones after the failed ones are lost.

So how do I write a transaction or query which has 10 insert statements after each other, but if one fails, it lets the rest getting inserted.

```
insert into hotels (hotel_id, hotel_name, batch_id)
    values ('18nt2f4jrqsqipf', 'Hotel Urban Flats Vienna City Center', '2019-02-04_20-35-22');
    values ('18nt2fajrqsqk4g', 'Hotel Appartements Castello', '2019-02-04_20-35-22');
    values ('18nt2ghjrqsqx5o', 'Bed and Breakfast Pension Bergkristall', '2019-02-04_20-35-22');
    values ('18nt2gnjrqsqv48', 'hotel garni corona: einfachheit und gastfreundschaft am comer see - scoene aussich im jeden jahreszeit - gaeste sind immer wilkommen', '2019-02-04_20-35-22');
    values ('18nt2gnjrqsqw41', 'Hotel Sommerhotel Don Bosco', '2019-02-04_20-35-22');
```

So in the 5th values clause, for the the hotel_name column, the data is longer than the data type.
How can I achieve, to either wrap this into a transaction (or just in normal query) on a way that if that one fails, the transaction still runs the next ones?
Thanks for the answers

(By the way the code preview shows my code without line breaks and indentations, although I used 4 space indentation and line breaks, sorry if those doesn't seem to be displayed)

Comment: See `INSERT IGNORE`

Comment: Yeah it has solved the issue... If you answer the question I can grant the solution to you. thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks, but it's too trivial and I really don't need the points.

Comment: I thank you anyway. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

After collecting data from required site try to write them in CSV file.
Then use MySQL `LOAD DATA` syntax to insert values from CSV file into table.

For more information check this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)

But make sure all items in your csv file should be compatible with your mysql table structure.